# ltxtable longtable with caption

Tags: captions, longtable, ltxtable

So i have a problem with the following MWE. When using the table environment to get the caption working, the longtable won't jump to the next page. If i don't use the table environment the caption won't work but the longtable will go onto the next page. I am sorry for the long MWE but i am asking for a friend and i am not sure what's save to remove.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, pdftex, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ltxtable} 
% figures in apa
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
 singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,labelfont=it,justification=justified,
 singlelinecheck=false,font=doublespacing}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % keine einrückung bei neuem absatz
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption[Eigenschaften der vier Umfrageplattformen]{Eigenschaften der vier Umfrageplattformen}
    \begin{longtable}{cXcccc}
        \toprule
         & SoSci Survey & LimeSurvey & SurveyMonkey & Unipark \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Allgemeines}\\
        \midrule
        Anzahl Umfragen beliebig & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Anzahl Fragen/ Umfrage & beliebig & ? & 10 & ? \\
        Anzahl Probanden/ Umfr. & 5000 & ? & 100 & ? \\
        Umfragezeitraum & 93 Tage\footnote{beliebig verlängerbar} & ? &  & ? \\
        Standort Server & München & ? & ? & ? \\
        Speicherplatz & 64 MB & ? & ? & ? \\
        Speicherdauer d. Daten & 3 Monate & ? & ? & ? \\
        Smartphone-Umfrage & \checkmark ? & ? & \checkmark ? & ? \\
        Download Umfrage & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Download Rohdaten & S, E, R, Q & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Fragebogenlink änderbar & \checkmark &  & \textit{\sffamily x} &  \\
        Einladungen & \Letter, URL  & ? & \Letter, URL & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Support}\\
        \midrule
        Bedienungsanleitung & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        Foren-Support & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        FAQ & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
        Beispielumfragen & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        24/7 E-Mail-Support & ? & ? & \checkmark & ? \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Inhalt}\\
        \midrule
        Verfügbare Fragetypen & > 30\footnote{individuell kombinierbar} & ? & 13 & ? \\
        Textbausteine? & \checkmark\footnote{grafisch und HTML} & ? & ? & ? \\
        Fortschrittsbalken & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Individuelle Seiten\footnote{Dank-Seite} & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Multimedia & A, V, T & ? & A, V? & ? \\
        Verschiedene Sprachen & \checkmark\footnote{auch innerhalb eines Fragebogens} & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Gestaltung}\\
        \midrule
        %Textformatierung in HTML & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        Beschriftungen anpassbar & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Benutzerdefiniertes Design & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Fußzeile anpassbar & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\\newpage
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Dynamik, Logik, Filter}\\
        \midrule
        %Dynamische Inhalte & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x}\footnote{nur Antwortoptionen} & ? \\
        Randomisierung & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x}\footnote{nur Antwortoptionen} & ? \\
        Fragenlogik & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Benutzerdef. Variablen & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Weiterleitung zu ext. Seiten & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Eigener PHP-Code & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Kontrollfunktionen}\\
        \midrule
        Pretest & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Antwortkontrolle d. Items & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\ 
        Antwortvalidierung & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Zugriffskontrolle & PW, IP, PL &  &  &  \\
        Rücklauf-Kontrolle & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        \bottomrule
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Inhalt}\\
        \midrule
        Verfügbare Fragetypen & > 30\footnote{individuell kombinierbar} & ? & 13 & ? \\
        Textbausteine? & \checkmark\footnote{grafisch und HTML} & ? & ? & ? \\
        Fortschrittsbalken & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Individuelle Seiten\footnote{Dank-Seite} & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Multimedia & A, V, T & ? & A, V? & ? \\
        Verschiedene Sprachen & \checkmark\footnote{auch innerhalb eines Fragebogens} & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Gestaltung}\\
        \midrule
        %Textformatierung in HTML & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        Beschriftungen anpassbar & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Benutzerdefiniertes Design & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Fußzeile anpassbar & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Dynamik, Logik, Filter}\\
        \midrule
        %Dynamische Inhalte & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x}\footnote{nur Antwortoptionen} & ? \\
        Randomisierung & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x}\footnote{nur Antwortoptionen} & ? \\
        Fragenlogik & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Benutzerdef. Variablen & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Weiterleitung zu ext. Seiten & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Eigener PHP-Code & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Kontrollfunktionen}\\
        \midrule
        Pretest & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Antwortkontrolle d. Items & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\ 
        Antwortvalidierung & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Zugriffskontrolle & PW, IP, PL &  &  &  \\
        Rücklauf-Kontrolle & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to get a caption to work with the current setup, am i overlooking something?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Off-Topic: You should not use `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`. If you do not like indent of the first line of a new paragraph, you should at least use paragraph separation. This can be done, using KOMA-Script option `parskip`. See the manual for information about the various setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `longtable` inside the `table` environment.

To get a caption inside `longtable` write (see the `\\` at the end of that line!)

```
\caption[Eigenschaften der vier Umfrageplattformen]{Eigenschaften der vier Umfrageplattformen}\\
```

With the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, pdftex, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ltxtable} 
% figures in apa
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
 singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,labelfont=it,justification=justified,
 singlelinecheck=false,font=doublespacing}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % keine einrückung bei neuem absatz
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
%\begin{table}
    %
    \begin{longtable}{cXcccc}
     \caption[Eigenschaften der vier Umfrageplattformen]{Eigenschaften der vier Umfrageplattformen}\\
        \toprule
         & SoSci Survey & LimeSurvey & SurveyMonkey & Unipark \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Allgemeines}\\
        \midrule
        Anzahl Umfragen beliebig & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Anzahl Fragen/ Umfrage   & beliebig & ? & 10 & ? \\
        Anzahl Probanden/ Umfr.  & 5000 & ? & 100 & ? \\
        Umfragezeitraum          & 93 Tage\footnote{beliebig verlängerbar} & ? &  & ? \\
        Standort Server          & München & ? & ? & ? \\
        Speicherplatz            & 64 MB & ? & ? & ? \\
        Speicherdauer d. Daten   & 3 Monate & ? & ? & ? \\
        Smartphone-Umfrage       & \checkmark ? & ? & \checkmark ? & ? \\
        Download Umfrage         & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Download Rohdaten        & S, E, R, Q & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Fragebogenlink änderbar  & \checkmark &  & \textit{\sffamily x} &  \\
        Einladungen              & \Letter, URL  & ? & \Letter, URL & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Support}\\
        \midrule
        Bedienungsanleitung & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        Foren-Support & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        FAQ & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
        Beispielumfragen & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        24/7 E-Mail-Support & ? & ? & \checkmark & ? \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Inhalt}\\
        \midrule
        Verfügbare Fragetypen & > 30\footnote{individuell kombinierbar} & ? & 13 & ? \\
        Textbausteine? & \checkmark\footnote{grafisch und HTML} & ? & ? & ? \\
        Fortschrittsbalken & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Individuelle Seiten\footnote{Dank-Seite} & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Multimedia & A, V, T & ? & A, V? & ? \\
        Verschiedene Sprachen & \checkmark\footnote{auch innerhalb eines Fragebogens} & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Gestaltung}\\
        \midrule
        %Textformatierung in HTML & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        Beschriftungen anpassbar & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Benutzerdefiniertes Design & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Fußzeile anpassbar & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\\newpage
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Dynamik, Logik, Filter}\\
        \midrule
        %Dynamische Inhalte & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x}\footnote{nur Antwortoptionen} & ? \\
        Randomisierung & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x}\footnote{nur Antwortoptionen} & ? \\
        Fragenlogik & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Benutzerdef. Variablen & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Weiterleitung zu ext. Seiten & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Eigener PHP-Code & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Kontrollfunktionen}\\
        \midrule
        Pretest & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Antwortkontrolle d. Items & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\ 
        Antwortvalidierung & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Zugriffskontrolle & PW, IP, PL &  &  &  \\
        Rücklauf-Kontrolle & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        \bottomrule

        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Inhalt}\\
        \midrule
        Verfügbare Fragetypen & > 30\footnote{individuell kombinierbar} & ? & 13 & ? \\
        Textbausteine? & \checkmark\footnote{grafisch und HTML} & ? & ? & ? \\
        Fortschrittsbalken & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Individuelle Seiten\footnote{Dank-Seite} & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Multimedia & A, V, T & ? & A, V? & ? \\
        Verschiedene Sprachen & \checkmark\footnote{auch innerhalb eines Fragebogens} & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Gestaltung}\\
        \midrule
        %Textformatierung in HTML & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        Beschriftungen anpassbar & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Benutzerdefiniertes Design & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Fußzeile anpassbar & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Dynamik, Logik, Filter}\\
        \midrule
        %Dynamische Inhalte & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x}\footnote{nur Antwortoptionen} & ? \\
        Randomisierung & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x}\footnote{nur Antwortoptionen} & ? \\
        Fragenlogik & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Benutzerdef. Variablen & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Weiterleitung zu ext. Seiten & \checkmark & ? & \textit{\sffamily x} & ? \\
        Eigener PHP-Code & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{Kontrollfunktionen}\\
        \midrule
        Pretest & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Antwortkontrolle d. Items & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\ 
        Antwortvalidierung & \checkmark & ? & \checkmark & ? \\
        Zugriffskontrolle & PW, IP, PL &  &  &  \\
        Rücklauf-Kontrolle & \checkmark & ? & ? & ? \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
%\end{table}
\end{document}
```

you get the result you want:

[image]

Please see that I moved package `hyperref` to be loaded as last package ...